# How to code a smoke test using Selenium IDE in this POST case, using id=nav-link-accountList as target; in a way that doesn´t get errors?

Tags: selenium-ide, smoke-testing

[this is the first part of the Selenium IDE smoke test coding displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtYQ7.png)
the case i am talking is how to continue coding my Seleninum IDE  smoke test until i can execute the command that uses the nav-link-accountList target in mercadolibre.com.co; what i have coded until now is showed in the pictures i attached in this POST message
[this is the second part of the Selenium IDE smoke test coding displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Do0.png)